# Type Problems In PyCharm?

Tags: types, typing

if im writing something before a thing i've already written, then it replaces it instead of inserting.

Example:

`print("Hello, World!")`

^

|

|

If i am trying to write something before right here,
it replaces the print with whatever I write.
How do I Fix it?

Comment: Check you don't have the `insert` key toggled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on your insert key of keyboard...